# How to post mutation Laravel GraphQL with VueJS Axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I have error when I use axios.post to Larvel GraphQL

My data() code

```
data() {
    return {
        name:"",
        content:"",
        data_post:{
            query:`
                mutation {
                    createGrammar(
                        name: "${this.name}",
                        content:"${this.content}",
                    ) {
                        id
                    }
                }
            `
        },
    };
},
```

And my methods code

```
methods:{
    createGrammar(){
        axios.post('/graphql',this.data_post)
            .then((response)=>{
                console.log(`${this.name}`);
                this.fetchGrammar();
            })
            .catch((error)=>console.log(error));
    },
}
```

When i send request I get value undefined, `${this.name}` can get data in `name` but when send to GraphQL, data in `name` change to undefined @@,And I test `name: "abc"`

Thanks